# Nordic nrf connect sdk 2.0.0 try to change the setting of periodic advertising example and get an error

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth-lowenergy

so I am working on Nordic nrf52840 periodic advertising and trying to scan the device using android app I write, but I can't find my device, the last few days I was working on the Rx(android app),I can't really find what's wrong with my code. Now I am trying to figure out what's wrong on the Tx(nrf52840) and I think I found the problem the parameters in bt_le_ext_adv_create() used to be BT_LE_EXT_ADV_NCONN_NAME which means Non-connectable extended advertising and I change it to BT_LE_EXT_ADV_SCAN_NAME which means Scannable extended advertising but after I change the setting the bt_le_per_adv_set_param() start poping error -22 which means Invalid argument.

```
    /*
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Nordic Semiconductor ASA
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#define DEVICE_NAME     "RECEIVER"
#define DEVICE_NAME_LEN (sizeof(DEVICE_NAME) - 1)
static uint8_t mfg_data[] = { 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10,
                          0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10};

static const struct bt_data ad[] = {
BT_DATA(BT_DATA_MANUFACTURER_DATA, mfg_data, 40),
};

void main(void)
{
struct bt_le_ext_adv *adv;
int err;

printk("Starting Periodic Advertising Demo\n");

/* Initialize the Bluetooth Subsystem */
err = bt_enable(NULL);
if (err) {
    printk("Bluetooth init failed (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Create a non-connectable non-scannable advertising set */
err = bt_le_ext_adv_create(BT_LE_EXT_ADV_SCAN_NAME, NULL, &adv); //  BT_LE_EXT_ADV_NCONN_NAME  BT_LE_EXT_ADV_SCAN_NAME
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to create advertising set (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Set periodic advertising parameters */
err = bt_le_per_adv_set_param(adv, BT_LE_PER_ADV_DEFAULT);
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to set periodic advertising parameters"
           " (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

/* Enable Periodic Advertising */
err = bt_le_per_adv_start(adv);
if (err) {
    printk("Failed to enable periodic advertising (err %d)\n", err);
    return;
}

while (true) {
    printk("Start Extended Advertising...");
    err = bt_le_ext_adv_start(adv, BT_LE_EXT_ADV_START_DEFAULT);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to start extended advertising "
               "(err %d)\n", err);
        return;
    }
    printk("done.\n");

    

    k_sleep(K_SECONDS(10));

    printk("Stop Extended Advertising...");
    err = bt_le_ext_adv_stop(adv);
    if (err) {
        printk("Failed to stop extended advertising "
               "(err %d)\n", err);
        return;
    }
    printk("done.\n");

    k_sleep(K_SECONDS(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a different app to scan for your device to rule out issues with your own app? I would recommend [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile).

Comment: HI @MichaelKotzjan Yes I did and nrf Connect can easily find my device which make me confused why my app can't find my device

Comment: Thanks for the update. If nRF Connect finds your device the problem is definetly within your app. Most of the times something like this pops up on StackOverflow this is a permission problem. Please open a new question regarding your app or read more about [Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)